# How do you pass different arguments to different work items in opencl?

Tags: opencl

I'm an absolute newbie to opencl and have been reading the documentation but I am missing something. It is my understanding that the advantage of work-groups is that each worker will be executing the same code for different data. I have been reading the documentation but I am missing how this is done. clSetKernelArg seems to be setting the kernel arguments for all workers so how do I collate a data set over the workers in a group so that each worker is working on it's own portion of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical approach is to pass a buffer, then have each work item work with a different element in the buffer, depending on its id.

```
kernel void f(global float* buffer) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    float x = buffer[x];
    // x is different in each work-item.
}
```

I recommend searching for some tutorials and code samples as you dive into OpenCL.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this may be the case but the documentation didn't make this clear. My other idea was that I may be able to use global memory synchronization (v2.0 atomic if available) and store an index in local memory.  You certainly saved me from writing a lot of bad code.

Comment: Just one question, can I use a local ID for the same purpose?

Comment: @RalphRitoch I don't know what documentation are you using, but I'd recommend checking some tutorials / samples first. Also, if I were you I'd avoid OpenCL 2.0 features until there's at least one implementation of it out there :-)

Comment: @RalphRitoch Regarding local IDs, you can use them but they have different semantic! When in doubt, use the formula: `get_global_id(dim) == get_group_id(dim) * get_local_size(dim) + get_local_id(dim) + get_global_offset(dim)`.

Comment: I was using OpenCL 2.0 documentation from the "Khronos Registry".  Today I realized my mistake and I've downloaded v1.2. As painful as the official specification is to read, I believe it will pay off in the long run even though it quadruples my learning curve.

Comment: @RalphRitoch In my experience the spec reads more like a reference than a manual. It's very useful, I just don't think it's the best place to start.

Comment: It is a little late since I've already started coding using Java+JOCL but I got stuck when it came to performing actual work (processing) with OpenCL. Can you suggest any tutorials the cover direct access to the OpenCL API (Such as provided by JOCL and C/C++)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48579/discussion-between-oak-and-ralph-ritoch)